# No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Can anyone please help me?
I am using devise with rails for the authentication.
I have these controllers:

```
Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

I use this controller below to list the users with different criteria

`class UsersController < ApplicationController`

Below is my routes:

```
devise_for :users,
         :controllers => {
            :registrations => "users/registrations"
          }
```

`resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :mentor_list] do
  collection do
    get 'leaders'  =>  'users#leaders_list'
    get 'mentors'  =>  'users#mentors_list'
    get 'students' =>  'users#students_list'
  end
    resources :addresses
 end`

below are my rake routes result:

```
 new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                            users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                   users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                           users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                              users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                                   users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                   users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                   users/registrations#destroy
           leaders_users GET    /users/leaders(.:format)                           users#leaders_list
           mentors_users GET    /users/mentors(.:format)                           users#mentors_list
          students_users GET    /users/students(.:format)                          users#students_list
          user_addresses GET    /users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)                addresses#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/addresses(.:format)                addresses#create
        new_user_address GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/new(.:format)            addresses#new
       edit_user_address GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id/edit(.:format)       addresses#edit
            user_address GET    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)            addresses#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)            addresses#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)            addresses#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/addresses/:id(.:format)            addresses#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                    root GET    /                                                  users#index
```

so what i am trying to do here is to let the leader creates users. But whenever I click on the submit button of the new User form I get this error below.

> ```
> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [POST] "/users/sign_up"
> ```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: you can't use "/users/sign_up" since it's a GET route, check in your rake routes.

Comment: So what is your recommendations

Comment: Your registration form is going to the wrong place. It looks like you should be sending it to `user_registration_path` if you're using POST.

Comment: If you want leaders to create users, you shouldn't use devise routes for that,  their purpose is to create users by registration, if you want to let leaders to create users you should create users controller, namespaced under leaders and define create action there.

Comment: Thank you all, I had `new_user_registration_path(resource_name)` so I changed it to `registration_path(resource_name)` and it is working well. now. to @JovicaŠuša to have a nother user create a user, just create a registration controller and manipulate the route just the way i did above and then add this line in the registration controller: `skip_before_action :require_no_authentication` Thank you again

Comment: @Idriss Thank you for the suggestion, did you succeed with this solution to limit user creation on leaders only?

Comment: @JovicaŠuša Yes I did, but I have a boolean field(check_box) that I use to verify if user is leader or whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear from your **rake routes** o/p that **Post /users/sign_up** is not defined.

```
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                   users/registrations#create
```

use the following route to create users.

Comment: Thanks, So How would I define it based on my routes?

Comment: As per the comments, looks like you solved. If not, i'll help. Also looks around devise documentation pages on github.